# How to combine dictionaries using one's values as the other's keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

```
data_map = {"field_1": "name_in_data"}
data_set = {"name_in_data": "data_value"}
```

I need to combine these two dictionaries into:

```
{"field_1" : "data_value"}
```

I wrote a simple loop to do this:

```
for key in data_map:
   data_map[key] = data_set[data_map[key]]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Do you need to update `data_map` in place, or is a new `dict` created from the original two OK?

Comment: What you have now is fine, though I would consider something like `for key, value in data_map.items(): data_map[key] = data_set[value]` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### 1. Return a new dictionary (leaving the original 2 untouched):

You could use a dictionary comprehension ([[Python.Docs]: Data Structures - Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)).

> ```py
> >>> data_map = {"field_1": "name_in_data"}
> >>> data_set = {"name_in_data": "data_value"}
> >>>
> >>> {k: data_set[v] for k, v in data_map.items() if v in data_set}
> {'field_1': 'data_value'}
> ```

It will ignore keys from *data_map* whose values are not keys in *data_set* (which I guess it's the expected behavior).

Continuation:

> ```py
> >>> # Add some dummy key: value in data_map
> >>> data_map[1] = 2
> >>> data_map
> {'field_1': 'name_in_data', 1: 2}
> >>> # Same result
> >>> {k: data_set[v] for k, v in data_map.items() if v in data_set}
> {'field_1': 'data_value'}
> ```

###### 2. Modify *data_map* in place (like in your example)

Either:

1. Use your method (with a slight modification: use *data_set.get* to handle the (same) case: key is not present in *data_set*)

   > ```py
   > >>> data_map = {"field_1": "name_in_data"}
   > >>> data_set = {"name_in_data": "data_value"}
   > >>>
   > >>> for k, v in data_map.items():
   > ...     data_map[k] = data_set.get(v, v)
   > ...
   > >>>
   > >>> data_map
   > {'field_1': 'data_value'}
   > ```
2. Use *dict.update* (and pass it a (new) dictionary (computed with the method at the beginning)):

   > ```py
   > >>> data_map = {"field_1": "name_in_data"}
   > >>>
   > >>> data_map.update({k: data_set[v] for k, v in data_map.items() if v in data_set})
   > >>>
   > >>> data_map
   > {'field_1': 'data_value'}
   > ```

Now, the 2<sup>nd</sup> (***#2.2.***) looks more *Python*ic (than ***2.1.***) and it's shorter, but it has the downside of creating a temporary dictionary.

Of course, one could also think of other methods, but they are variations of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the *items*, so the values don't need to be looked up:

```
for key, value in data_map.items():
    data_map[key] = data_set[value]
```

Or let the methods do the work:

```
data_map.update(zip(
    data_map,
    map(data_set.get, data_map.values())
))
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary comprehension:

new_dict = {k1:v2 for v1, v2 in data_set.items() for k1, v1 in data_map.items()}

Comment: This creates a new `dict` object, rather than updating the original in-place. That may or may not be an issue for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `update` method with a dict comprehension like so:

```py
data_map.update({field: data_set[name] for field, name in data_map.items()})
print(data_map)
```

---

```
{'field_1': 'data_value'}
```